# How do you get Cypress to select a certain icon within a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, cypress

Im quite new with Cypress, and have been having some great luck with the library.
But find myself stuck on this specific situation.

I am stuck on a selecting a button on a specific div that contains specific text.
I need to click on a button depending on what the sibling divs contain.

Our layout looks something like this:

```
<div class="MuiList-root">
  <div class="MuiListItem-root">
    <div class="MuiListItemText-root">
      Whatever 1
    </div>
    <div class="MuiListItemIcon-root">
      <button type="button" onClick={()=>{...}}>Delete</button
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="MuiListItem-root">
    <div class="MuiListItemText-root">
      Delete This One
    </div>
    <div class="MuiListItemIcon-root">
      <button type="button" onClick={()=>{...}}>Delete</button
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="MuiListItem-root">
    <div class="MuiListItemText-root">
      Whatever 2
    </div>
    <div class="MuiListItemIcon-root">
      <button type="button" onClick={()=>{...}}>Delete</button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The goal is the click the "Delete" button on the ".MuiListItem-root" that contains "Delete This One".
The list is dynamic, so Im unable to use the position of the item.

** **Hacky Solution that works - There has to be a better way** **

```
    // Clicks the edit button - There has to be a better way of clicking the elements delete button.
    cy.get("[id='stuff'] .MuiTypography-displayBlock").then((elements)=>{
      Object.keys(elements).forEach((item,index)=>{
        let classificationIndex
        if(elements[item].textContent === `Delete This One`) {
          classificationIndex = index

          cy.get("[type='button']").eq(classificationIndex).click()
        }
      })
    })
```

I get a little more specific, then find the index of the element that reads "Delete This One".
Once I know the index, i then grab the buttons and click on the "Delete" of that specific index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this. As your description says, go to the `.MuiListItemText-root` and find it's sibling,

```js
cy.contains('.MuiListItemText-root', 'Delete This One')  // get the div with the text
  .siblings()                                            // get sibling elements
  .eq(0)                                                 // take the first (and only)
  .find('button')                                        // find button within
  .click()
```

but `.contains()` also finds text within descendants so you can target the MuiListItem directly and save some steps

```js
cy.contains('.MuiListItem-root', 'Delete This One')      // get grandparent of text 
  .find('button')                                        // find button within
  .click()
```

Comment: Well god damn,
I recon if it were a snake, it would of jumped right up a bit me!

Thats it! Thank you!